# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet launching debug on pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pycharm, virtualenv

I have a Django (version 1.9) application running with python 2.7.10 and I'm using Virtualenv.
Running the application with `./manage.py runserver` I've no error, but when I try to run in debug I get `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

Here is the Pycharm debugging configuration:

[image]

Any idea why?
Here is the complete stack trace:

```
   /Users/matteobetti/Progetti/Enydros/enysoft/bin/python ./manage.py runserver
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/Users/matteobetti/Progetti/Enydros/enysoft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/Users/matteobetti/Progetti/Enydros/enysoft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/Users/matteobetti/Progetti/Enydros/enysoft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 176, in fetch_command
        commands = get_commands()
      File "/Users/matteobetti/Progetti/Enydros/enysoft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 100, in wrapper
        result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
      File "/Users/matteobetti/Progetti/Enydros/enysoft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 71, in get_commands
        for app_config in reversed(list(apps.get_app_configs())):
      File "/Users/matteobetti/Progetti/Enydros/enysoft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
        self.check_apps_ready()
      File "/Users/matteobetti/Progetti/Enydros/enysoft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
        raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
    django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I add `import django` e `django.setup` before `execute_from_command_line(sys.argvs)`

and I get this stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matteobetti/Progetti/Enydros/enysoft/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/matteobetti/Progetti/Enydros/enysoft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/matteobetti/Progetti/Enydros/enysoft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/matteobetti/Progetti/Enydros/enysoft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/matteobetti/Progetti/Enydros/enysoft/frontend/apps.py", line 2, in <module>
    from frontend.services.container import app_context
  File "/Users/matteobetti/Progetti/Enydros/enysoft/frontend/services/container.py", line 1, in <module>
    from frontend.services.enysoft_services import RService, FixedSizeDirectoryCache, TubeSectionService, CsvSanifier
  File "/Users/matteobetti/Progetti/Enydros/enysoft/frontend/services/enysoft_services.py", line 5, in <module>
    import rpy2.robjects as ro
  File "/Users/matteobetti/Progetti/Enydros/enysoft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File "/Users/matteobetti/Progetti/Enydros/enysoft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    tmp = subprocess.check_output(("R", "RHOME"), universal_newlines=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Another thing to say is that my colleagues with Linux have no problem with the same *virtualenv* configuration, the only one that has a problem is me, using MacOs.

Comment: are you using Community edition?

Comment: yes. pycharm 2016.1.3 on mac os

Comment: did you solve it ?running on same problem

Answer (score 2):

Try to add you settings file to system `PATH`. In my projects settings are in the folder /project_name/project_name/settings/development.py (that is slightly different from standard way). And in my case Evironment variables string is

`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project_name.settings.development;PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`

So change it according to your parameters and then try to run server again. I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand, i haven't any development.py file in my projects. settings are in /project_name/project_name/settings.py. What should i add to that file?

Comment: than in your case the line will be `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project_name.settings;PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`

Comment: I add DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project_name.settings;PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1, in the field Envinronment variables on pychharm Run/Debug Configuration, but i get the same error.

Comment: I found one another possible issue - in your manage.py add this to the top - `import django` and this line - `django.setup()` just before line `execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)`

Comment: i've edite the question with a new stack trace. Any idea? :(